# ajax Cannot POST /index.html cordova

Tags: ajax, cordova

```js
          <script>
            $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost/app/connexion.php",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      /*contentType: 'application/json',
      data: '{ email: "hajjajihajer24@gmail.com", password : "00000" }',*/
      data: $("#connexionForm").serialize(), 

      success: function(msg){
                              if(msg == "1") {
                                  $("#status").text("Login Success..!");
                               
                              }
                              },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          console.log(textStatus + jqXHR.responseText);
      }
  });
```

```html
<form action=""class="sign-in-form" method="POST" id="connexionForm" name="connexionForm">
                  <h2 class="title"> S'indetifier </h2>
                  <div class="input-field">
                    <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
     
         <input type="text" placeholder="Nom Utilisateur" name="email" id="email"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="input-field">
                    <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Mote de passe"   id="password" name="password" />
                  </div>
                  <p id="status"></p>
                  <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn solid"  id="loginButton" onclick="ValidateEmail(document.connexionForm.login)"  />
                </form>
```

I'm building a Cordova APP with simple REST calls.

The issue is when I make a AJAX with POST, Chrome sends me: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/app/connexion. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405" on console.
and return   Cannot POST /index.html
But, if I make a AJAX call with GET (basically return an value from database) the things works like a charm.

Comment: You are making two requests. One on your form with `<form action="" method="POST">` and another with AJAX. Get rid of the <form> code and try again.

Comment: I try that but ajax  read the data from form

Comment: Then try adding onsubmit preventDefault to the `<form>` instead like so: `<form action="" class="sign-in-form" method="POST" id="connexionForm" name="connexionForm" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); return false;">`